# Find a Registry key's name by its value?

Tags: registry, windows-server-2008, registrykey

I have a registry key value - but I dont know what key it is I need to alter (as the value is incorrect)

Is there a way I can find out?

I'm getting an error with an add-in and its caused by a \ existing in the file address - would like to find the relevant registry key and alter it :)

I'm on Windows Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try searching through the registry in `regedit.exe` (Edit/Find...)